# Rails file_field not uploading image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My Controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @articles = Article.organise
    end

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        @article.update(article_params)
        redirect_to @article
    end

    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)
        @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    end

    def destroy
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        @article.destroy
        redirect_to articles_path
    end


    private

    def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :brief, :posted_by, :posted_at, :posted_from, :image_file_name)
    end



end
```

My View:

```
  <p>
      <%= f.label :Image %><br/>
      <%= f.file_field :image_file_name %>
  </p>
```

My Model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.organise
        order("posted_at desc")
    end



end
```

My Params In Controller:

```
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :brief, :posted_by, :posted_at, :posted_from, :image_file_name)
end
```

Is returning this error, I think it has something to with the controller params but i'm not quite sure.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ArticlesController#create
 TypeError: can't cast ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile to string: INSERT INTO "articles" ("brief", "created_at", "image_file_name", "posted_at", "posted_by", "posted_from", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Post your full code of `ArticlesController`

Comment: ...and your Article model please

Comment: Are you using Carrierwave? or trying to store the image directly in the database?

Comment: Directly to data base for now, my comlumn type is string for the image, could this be the cause?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are not using any gems for file upload.

```
<%= form_for @article, {},:html => {:multipart => true } do |f| %>
 <p>
  <%= f.label :Image %><br/>
  <%= f.file_field 'file' %>
  <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
 </p>
<% end %>
```

Add this in your create action and upload to same server location /assets/images

```
if params[:article].present?
 file = params[:article][:file]
 File.open(Rails.root.join('app','assets', 'images', file.original_filename), 'wb') do |f|
  f.write(file.read)
 end
end
```